# Pastry not "sticking" to beef Wellington

Tags: beef, pastry, presentation

I've cooked a Wellington a couple of times and whilst I've been pleased with the overall outcome on each occasion the pastry comes away when serving. This is purely for aesthetic reasons.

I use a 1kg fillet, seared, then rolled in to a sausage on a bed of prosciutto ham and a mushroom duxelle with some chicken liver pate mixed in.

I chill this before wrapping in egg washed puff pastry and cooking for about 40 minutes. This has resulted in rare beef, a good crisp pastry that holds its form until cutting it for serving.

It wasn't too wet - it just seems the pastry doesn't want to affix itself to the contents.

Any ideas on how to improve this?

I adapted my recipe from this one http://www.bbcgoodfood.com/recipes/2538/beef-wellington

Comment: How do you prepare the mushroom duxelle?

Comment: I think we're missing some information here, is the pastry homemade or is it store bought ? What pastry did you use before (when it worked), compared to the one that does not "stick" ? Is it the same brand ? Did you use the same pastry recipe ?

Answer (score 4):

I never find that the pastry actually "sticks" to the contents when making a wellington. The meat will shrink slightly as it cooks so the pastry you have wrapped around it will have a certain amount of space between it and the contents.

Try cutting thicker servings and making sure you have a well sharpened, long bladed knife to cut it with. Use the entire length of the blade with long strokes to get through the pastry and meat as smoothly as possible. This should stop the pastry breaking or falling away, then when you serve it will at least appear to be stuck on.

Hope that helps!